# Number of connected components of the intersection of two maximal tori

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected complex semisimple Lie group and $S$, $T$ two maximal tori in $G$. Is there a known upper bound on the number of connected components of $S\cap T$? For example, is it bounded by the cardinality of the centre $Z_G$:
$$|\pi_0(S\cap T)|\leq|Z_G|?$$

Comment: We have $Z_G\subseteq S\cap T$ which induces a map $Z_G\to\pi_0(S\cap T)$. It would suffice to show that this map is surjective, i.e. that every $g\in S\cap T$ can be written $g=zh$ for $z\in Z_G$ and $h$ in the identity component of $S\cap T$.

Comment: @Thomas:  Two quick comments.  1) What happens when $G$ has trivial center (for example, types $G_2, F_4, E_8$)?    2) The question seems to make good sense for any semisimple algebraic group over an algebraically closed field of any characteristic.    Is there anything special here about the Lie group settting?

Comment: For connected semisimple $G$ over any field $k$, the adjoint case (for which you ask if $S \cap T$ is connected) implies even divisibility into the size of the etale part of $Z_G$. Indeed, for the adjoint central quotient $\overline{G}=G/Z_G$ and maximal torus images $\overline{S}$ and $\overline{T}$, the map of $k$-tori $(S \cap T)^0_{\rm{red}} \to (\overline{S} \cap \overline{T})^0_{\rm{red}}$ is an isogeny. Thus, if $\overline{S}\cap\overline{T}$ is connected then $Z_G\to \pi_0(S\cap T)$ is surjective (as suggested by SHP above), so we would win. Not sure if the adjoint case should hold.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Summary:** Let $X = \mathrm{Hom}(T,\mathbb{G}_m)$ be the weight lattice, $\Phi \subset X$ the root system. Define a sublattice $L$ of $X$ to be a "root sublattice" if $L$ is generated as an abelian group by $L \cap \Phi$. Then the possible component groups of $S \cap T$ are the torsion subgroups of $X/L$, as $L$ ranges over root sublattices.

This will follow from:

**Theorem:** Let $Z$ be a subgroup of $T$. Then there exists a maximal torus $S$ with $S \cap T = Z$ if and only if there is a connected subgroup $H$ with $T \subseteq H \subseteq G$ such that $Z = Z(H)$.

We first make some comments about connected groups $H$ with $T \subseteq H \subseteq G$. Write $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{t} \oplus \bigoplus_{\beta \in \Phi} \mathfrak{g}_{\beta}$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{t}$ are the Lie algebras of $G$ and $T$ and $\mathfrak{g}_{\beta}$ are the root spaces.

Connected subgroups are determined by their Lie subalgebras, and a subalgebra containing $\mathfrak{t}$ must be of the form $\mathfrak{t} \oplus \bigoplus_{\beta \in I} \mathfrak{g}_{\beta}$ for some subset $I$ of $\Phi$. More specifically, $\mathfrak{t} \oplus \bigoplus_{\beta \in \Phi} \mathfrak{g}_{\beta}$  will be a Lie-sub-algebra if and only if, for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2 \in I$, if $\beta_1+\beta_2 \in \Phi$ then $\beta_1 + \beta_2 \in I$. For such an $I$, we write $H_I$ for the corresponding connected subgroup. We note that there are only finitely many $H_I$, since there are only finitely many subsets of $\Phi$.

For any such $I$, set $J = I \cap (-I)$. Then $H_J$ is a reductive subgroup of $G$, and we have a short exact sequence $0 \to N_{I \setminus J} \to H_I \to H_J \to 0$ where $N_{I \setminus J}$ is the unipotent group corresponding to $\bigoplus_{\beta \in I \setminus J} \mathfrak{g}_{\beta}$. This sequence is semidirect.

**Lemma:** The centralizer of $T$ in any $H_I$ is $T$.

**Proof:** Let $J = I \cap (-I)$ and consider the above semidirect sequence  $0 \to N_{I \setminus J} \to H_I \to H_J \to 0$. Let $\pi$ be the map $H_I \to H_J$. Let $Z_{H_I}(T)$ be the centralizer of $T$ in $H_I$. Then $\pi(Z_{H_I}(T)) \subseteq Z_{H_J}(T) = T$, where the latter inequality is standard. On the other hand, $T$ clearly does centralize $T$. So we have $T \subseteq Z_{H_I}(T) \subseteq \pi^{-1}(T)$ and thus we have a short exact sequence $0 \to N_{I \setminus J} \cap Z_{H_I}(T) \to  Z_{H_I}(T) \to T \to 0$. But the Lie algebra of  $N_{I \setminus J}$ is a direct sum of weight spaces for $T$ with nonzero character, so no element of $N_{I \setminus J}$ centralizes $T$. We deduce that $N_{I \setminus J} \cap Z_{H_I}(T)$ is trivial, so $Z_{H_I}(T) = T$. $\square$

**Corollary:** The center of $H_I$ is contained in $T$.

**Proof:** Clearly, the center of $H_I$ centralizes $T$. $\square$.

We can now show that $S \cap T$, for any maximal torus $S$, is of the form $Z(H_I)$ for some $I$. Let $H$ be the Lie-sub-group generated by $S$ and $T$. Clearly, $T \subseteq H$
and $H$ is connected, so $H$ is of the form $H_I$ for some $I$. By the corollary, $Z(H_I) \subseteq T$ and similarly $Z(H_I) \subseteq T$. This shows $Z(H_I) \subseteq S \cap T$. On the other hand, $S$ and $T$ commute with every element of $S \cap T$, so $H_I$ commutes with every element of $S \cap T$ and we have $S \cap T \subseteq Z(H_I)$. We have proven both containments.

We now know that all intersections are of the form $Z(H_I)$. We want to show, in reverse, that any group of the form $Z(H_I)$ occurs as $S \cap T$. Given $I$, let $L \subseteq X$ be the lattice generated by $I$.  Let $K = L \cap \Phi$. Then $Z(H_I)$ is the subgroup of $T$ on which the characters of $L$ vanish, and we thus deduce that $Z(H_I) = Z(H_K)$. So it is enough to show that $Z(H_K)$ is of the form $S \cap T$. The group $H_K$ is reductive, so all we need is

**Lemma:** Let $H_K$ be as above. There is a maximal torus $S$ in $H_K$ such that $S \cap T = Z(H_K)$.

**Proof:**  Let $Y = \bigcup_{K' \subsetneq K} H_{K'}$. Then $Y$ is a union of finitely many subgroups of lower dimension, so the complement of $Y$ is Zariski dense. Let $s$ be a regular element in $H_K \setminus Y$, and let $S$ be the connected centralizer of $s$. We claim that $S \cap T = Z(H_K)$. We know that every maximal torus in $H_K$ contains $Z(H_K)$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $t \in T \setminus Z(H_K)$ and $t \in S$. Let $Z(t)$ be the centralizer of $t$ in $H_K$; since $t$ is not central, $Z(t)$ is not $H_K$. Let $Z(t)_0$ be the connected component of the identity of $Z(t)$. So $Z(t)_0$ is a connected subgroup of $H_K$ containing $T$, and must be of the form $H_{K'}$ for some $K' \subsetneq K$. Also, since $t \in S$, we have $S \subseteq Z(t)_0$. So $s \in H_{K'}$, contrary to the choice of $s$. We have obtained a contradiction, and deduce that $S \cap T = Z(H_K)$.

We have now proven the theorem. As we noted above, $Z(H_I)$ is the subgroup of $T$ where the characters in $I$ vanish. We deduce that $Z(H_I)$ is the dual group to $X/\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}} I$ and the component group of $Z(H_I)$ is the torsion subgroup of $X/\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}} I$.

---

What remains is combinatorics.

As nfdc23 suggests, it is convenient to work with the adjoint form of the group, in which case $X = \mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}} \Phi$. For the general case, multiply all bounds by $|X / \mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}} \Phi| = |Z(G)|$. I'll list the root sublattices  and state the largest one. Proofs will be provided if requested. I've chosen

In $A_n$, the root sublattices are $A_{n_1} \oplus A_{n_2} \oplus \cdots A_{n_r}$ for $\sum n_i = n$ and $Z(H_I)$ is trivial.

In $B_n$, we obviously have $B_{n_1} \oplus B_{n_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus B_{n_r}$. Each of these $B_m$'s, in turn, contain $D_m$ and $A_{m-1}$. The largest index comes from $D_2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ giving index $2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$. Here $\lfloor x \rfloor$ means $x$ rounded down, and $D_2 = \{ \pm e_1 \pm e_2 \} \subset B_2 = \{ \pm e_1 \pm e_2, \pm e_1, \pm e_2 \}$.

In $C_n$, we obviously have $C_{n_1} \oplus C_{n_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus C_{n_r}$ and we also have $A_{m-1} \subset C_m$. The largest index comes from $C_1^{\oplus n}$, that is to say, from $\{ \pm 2 e_i \}$ inside $C_n = \{ \pm 2 e_i, \pm e_i \pm e_j \}$, with index $2^n$.

In $D_n$, we obviously have $D_{n_1} \oplus D_{n_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus D_{n_r}$ and we also have $A_{m-1} \subset D_m$. The largest index comes from $D_2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$, giving $2^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor -1}$.

The exceptional types seem like a pain, but they definitely harbor some surprises! Both $A_8$ and $D_8$ are root sublattices of $E_8$, with index $3$ and $2$ respectively.

Comment: Analytification defines an equivalence of categories from connected semisimple $\mathbf{C}$-groups to connected complex Lie groups with semisimple Lie algebra, with algebraic subtori corresponding to analytic subtori, so it is equivalent (and better!) to think in terms of linear algebraic groups. It is a standard fact over any field $k$ that a maximal $k$-torus $S$ in a connected reductive (e.g., connected semisimple) $k$-group $H$ is its own centralizer in $H$ (a finer assertion than the Lie algebra analogue, since the centralizer might have been disconnected), so $S$ contains $Z(H)$.

Comment: The statement that for "$H$ any closed connected subgroup of $G$ containing $T$ … if $S$ is a generic other maximal torus of $H$, we have $Z(H) = S \cap T$" is not obvious to me.  (Perhaps it's because I don't know what 'generic' means.)  You probably also want to require that $H$ be reductive (but maybe it's enough just to require that it contain a maximal torus, as you do?).

Comment: @LSpice I believe it is still true for non-reductive. For example, let $H$ be the Borel $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} t&u\\0&t^{-1} \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ of $SL_2$.  The maximal tori of $H$ are of the form $T_c:= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} t&c (t^{-1} -  t)  \\ 0 & t^{-1} \end{smallmatrix} \right)$. If $c_1 \neq c_2$, then $T_{c_1} \cap T_{c_2} = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} \pm 1 &0 \\ 0 & \pm 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)=Z(H)$. But I need to think a little to write down a proof in general.

Comment: My "you probably require" is wrong:  as @nfdc23 argues, any maximal torus in $H$ contains $Z(H)$ as long as $H$ is a subgroup (even disconnected!) of a connected reductive group $G$ that contains a maximal torus of $G$, so certainly $S \cap T$ contains $Z(H)$; but it is not true that any maximal torus in *any* connected Lie group contains its centre.  (Think of a unipotent group.)  I still don't understand 'generic', though.

Comment: In your examples, the H_I might be off by a central extension.  E.g. PGL(a) x PGL(b) is not usually a subgroup of PGL(a+b).

Comment: Grr, you're right. I wrote it the first time with root systems; then thought it was more legible with groups but got it wrong. Sometime this weekend, I'll go through and fix everything.

Comment: @LSpice: Beyond the setting of connected compact Lie groups or connected complex Lie groups with semisimple Lie algebra (both of which are "algebraic" objects in a strong sense), the purely (real or complex)-analytic notion of "torus" is problematic in multiple ways (due to the exponential map $\mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}^{\times}$, etc). So I think it is a mistake to carry out a non-trivial discussion about tori in the analytic framework; it is clearer and avoids all sorts of headaches to move as rapidly as possible to the algebraic side and thereby not be distracted by analytic issues.

Comment: @LSpice See if this makes more sense.

Comment: @nfdc23, indeed, I was implicitly thinking in the algebraic-group setting.  Are you saying that, for example, the unipotent radical of the Borel subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ would be called a torus, as diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^\times$—or just that, because it *looks* like a torus, it shows that the notion of 'torus' in the abstract Lie-group setting is bogus?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, OK, I think I buy it.  (I proposed a few edits that I think correct minor typos and elisions.)  It may make more sense to prove your structure results for *any* reductive group, where they remain valid and the proofs may involve fewer subscripts, and then specialise to the various $H_K$.  (For example, rather than "The centraliser of $T$ in any $H_I$ is $T$", I think it is clearer to say something like "The centraliser of a maximal torus in a reductive Lie group is that torus.")

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, I only meant that as an abstract analytic concept it is problematic (beyond the compact case). For a semisimple Lie group we can require the adjoint representation of the "torus" consist of semisimple automorphisms (distinguishes $U(\mathbf{R})$ and $D(\mathbf{R})$ as subgroups of ${\rm{SL}}_2(\mathbf{R})$, with $D$ the split diagonal $\mathbf{R}$-torus and $U$ the unipotent radical of a Borel $\mathbf{R}$-subgroup containing $D$). But $\mathbf{R}^{\times}$ is disconnected, as is ${\rm{PGL}}_2(\mathbf{R})$, so other headaches ensue if one loses contact with algebraic structure.

Comment: @LSpice: Likewise, I think the concept of "reductive Lie group" (as a purely analytic concept, without reference to some "nearby" algebraic structure) beyond the semisimple case is somewhat problematic, due to disconnectedness issues and so on.  If one works analytically with a connected Lie group having semisimple Lie algebra (perhaps that is what "semisimple Lie group" means; I am never sure what is intended with connectedness) then there is a bit less confusion, but these conditions are not so nicely-behaved for inductive arguments, as you know.